# CodeIgniter continuing a foreach loop after another one has been run through

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 separate foreach loops being executed in the following code. At the end I have $row->websiteURL outputting right after the second foreach loop. The problem is $row->websiteURL is part of the first loop. So I get the following error when I run the code:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$websiteURL
>
> Filename: views/projects.php
>
> Line Number: 135
>
> " target="_blank">

How would I go about continuing the first foreach loop after the second foreach is complete?

```
<table style="width: 41%">
<?php   $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY idprojects DESC");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 15px">
        <div class="auto-style2">
            <em><span class="auto-style1"><?=$row->projectName?></span></div>
        <table cellpadding="5" style="width: 535px; height: 66;">
            <tr>
                <td class="box1" style="height: 49px; width: 800px;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 466px; height: 185px">
            <!-- MSTableType="layout" -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="width: 225px">
            <em>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr class="box1">
                <td class="innerbox" style="height: 88px"><em><span class="text1">Project name</span>:
                <span class="underlined-link"><?=$row->projectName?></span><br>
                <span class="text1">Description</span>: <?=$row->projectDesc?><br><span class="text1">Start 
                date</span>: <?=$row->startDate?><br><span class="text1">Finised date</span>: 
                <?=$row->finishedDate?><br><span class="text1">Created for</span>: 
                <?=$row->createdFor?><br><span class="text1">Contributers</span>:
                <span class="underlined-link"><?=$row->contributors?></span></em></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </em></td>
                <td style="width: 12px">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="top" style="height: 185px; width: 229px">
            <em>
<?php           $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM screenshots ORDER BY idscreenshot DESC");
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>
                <img alt="" src="<?=$row->screenshotURI?>" width="231" height="187"></em>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
        </table>
                <br>
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="<?=$row->websiteURL?>" target="_blank"><div class="link1">
                    View This Product</div></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </em></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: First off, why are you doing a query of the db in your view? This should be done in the model. Give me a second and I step through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your variables in the second foreach like this:

```
 $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM screenshots ORDER BY idscreenshot DESC");
                foreach ($query->result() as $row2) { ?>
                <img alt="" src="<?=$row2->screenshotURI?>" width="231" height="187"></em>&nbsp;</td>
```

The $row variable is still in scope and it's looking in the first query for this. If you are doing an inner foreach loop you can't name the "item" variable the same as the outter foreach.

so more to the point:

```
foreach($arr as $row):
   foreach($arr as $row2):
      //do something
   endforeach;
 endforeach;
```

Back to the bigger issue. You should not being querying data in the views. Data is manipulated in the Model. The controller loads the model, uses the model to get the information, then passes the info to the view. It can be a difficult concept to grasp if you're new to MVC. Once you get this working, focus on moving these queries into their own functions in your model and retrieving the information that way.

Comment: I forgot about that. thanks man. And I usually put my stuff in a controller. I don't mess with models. It takes up more time and I'm usually on a time constraint. And most people keep telling me on here to place my data that deals with the view inside the view. So I've just gotten into that habit.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't listen to them. Once your sites start getting a decent size you really need your data located in the views. You'll find that when you have lots of views and need to make one change to one query that's used 18 times, now you have to make that changes everywhere.. instead of just one place in the model. But, whatever works for you, lol.